# Customize the expand/ collapse button in ext js grid/ accordion

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Is there any way to customise the expand(+)/ collapse(-) buttons in ExtJs grid/ accordion.

Comment: How do you want to customize the accordion? Is it just by changing the button position, icon etc?

Comment: I want to change those icons.

Comment: On inspecting, I have found that they have used background images for those. Overriding those classes might help but I don't think its best practice.

Comment: yes @SreenathPG : you need to override that icon class for expand collapse.And it wont hamper any kind of best practice, because we are doing customization.

Comment: What if I want to customise those button for a particular grid, overriding those classes might affect the rest of grids/ accordions. Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the icons by overriding the CSS for tool icons. You can add a class name to the accordion panel and apply styles to the tool buttons using that.

**Sample Code Snippet**

```js
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
  title: 'Accordion Layout',
  width: 200,
  height: 300,
  layout: {
    type: 'accordion'
  },
  cls: 'my-accordion',
  items: [{
    title: 'Panel 1',
    html: 'Panel content!'
  }, {
    title: 'Panel 2',
    html: 'Panel content!',
    collapsed: true
  }, {
    title: 'Panel 3',
    html: 'Panel content!',
    collapsed: true
  }],
  renderTo: Ext.get("container")
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
}

.my-accordion .x-accordion-hd .x-tool-over .x-tool-collapse-top,
.my-accordion .x-accordion-hd .x-tool-over .x-tool-collapse-bottom,
.my-accordion .x-accordion-hd .x-tool-collapse-top,
.my-accordion .x-accordion-hd .x-tool-collapse-bottom {
  background-position: 0 -570px;
}

.my-accordion .x-accordion-hd .x-tool-over .x-tool-expand-top,
.my-accordion .x-accordion-hd .x-tool-over .x-tool-expand-bottom,
.my-accordion .x-accordion-hd .x-tool-expand-top,
.my-accordion .x-accordion-hd .x-tool-expand-bottom {
  background-position: 0 525px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Previous code was also fine in answer. Its good to include css too.

Comment: Hi, Sreenath, Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.